# What is the fastest way to generate a list of the lengths of sub-strings in a string, given a separator?

Tags: python

I have a string and I need to generate a list of the lengths of all the sub-strings terminating in a given separator.

For example: string = 'a0ddb0gf0', separator = '0', so I need to generate: lengths = [2,4,3], since len('a0')==2, len('ddb0')=4, and len('gf0')==3.

I am aware that it can be done by the following (for example):

```
separators = [index for index in range(len(string)) if string[index]==separator]
lengths = [separators[index+1] - separators[index] for index in range(len(separators)-1)]
```

But I need it to be done extremely fast (on large amounts of data). Generating an intermediate list for large amounts of data is time consuming.

Is there a solution that does this neatly and fast (py2.7)?

Comment: If you need faster still, you can write a function in cython

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastest? Don't know. You might like to profile it.

```
>>> print [len(s) for s in 'a0ddb0gf0'.split('0')]
[1, 3, 2, 0]
```

And, if you really don't want to include zero length strings:

```
>>> print [len(s) for s in 'a0ddb0gf0'.split('0') if s]
[1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: @Jeff : buyer beware: on very long strings, `split()` may be relatively slow (as you said in your question).

Comment: I just finished testing all the solutions, and unless I made a mistake, it appears that yours is the fastest, even on very large strings. Barely ahead of Ned Batchelder's solution, but neater/more pythonic, about 1/3 the time of JBernardo's solutions, and easily ahead of the others and mine.

Comment: @jeff what was your testing methodology?

Comment: `start = time.time()`; 
`lengths = [len(s)+1 for s in string.split('0')]`; 
`end = time.time()`; 
`print('1) seconds: %s' % str(end-start))`; etc, one after another
'

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I love [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sep = '0'
>>> data = 'a0ddb0gf0'
>>> [sum(1 for i in g) for (k, g) in groupby(data, sep.__ne__) if k]
[1, 3, 2]
```

This groups the data according to whether each element is equal to the separator, then gets the length of each group for which the element was not equal (by summing 1's for each item in the group).

itertools functions are generally quite fast, though I don't know for sure how much better than `split()` this is. The one point that I think is strongly in its favor is that this can seamlessly handle multiple consecutive occurrences of the separator character. It will also handle any iterable for `data`, not just strings.

Comment: `sep.__ne__` is faster than the lambda

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm pretty sure `.split` is faster but this is more efficient since it doesn't store a list in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how fast this will go, but here's another way:

```
def len_pieces(s, sep):
    i = 0
    while True:
        f = s.find(sep, i)
        if f == -1:
            yield len(s) - i
            return
        yield f - i + 1
        i = f + 1
```

Comment: the last line should be `i = f + 1` otherwise you will have an infinite loop

Comment: Two things wrong with this implementation, otherwise it's probably the fastest (only one that's O(n)). (1) You'll loop infinitely because you always start your next search at the location of the last separator (use `i = f + 1` instead). (2) The element following the last separator doesn't get a length assigned (as you bail out as soon as no separator can be found anymore).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [len(i) for i in re.findall('.+?0', 'a0ddb0gf0')]
[2, 4, 3]
```

You may use `re.finditer` to avoid an intermediary list, but it may not be much different in performance:

```
[len(i.group(0)) for i in re.finditer('.+?0', 'a0ddb0gf0')]
```

Comment: Interestingly, my tests have shown that your first solution appears to faster than the second!

Comment: @Jeff That always happens with small iterators in Python. Making a list is faster.

Comment: @Jeff also, if you're gonna test speed, you should use a compiled regex.

Comment: Tried that too, but it seems to make little or no difference for a regex of such little complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using an re:

```
[len(m.group()) for m in re.finditer('(.*?)0', s)]
```